# why is "schizophrenia" pronounced with a t sound?

Tags: pronunciation

One of the ways the word "schizophrenia" is pronounced is ˈskɪt.sə.ˈfri.ni.ə/

My question is where does the t sound in ˈskɪt come from as I can not see any reason for it?

Comment: Because the original word is German (Schizophrenie) and in German the 'z' makes a 't' sound.

Comment: @V0ight You mean the /ts/ sound.

Comment: Fascinating. Actually it is made up of two ancient Greek words but since it is coined by Germans for the first time it is pronounced the way Germans would pronounce it. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Actually, Germans pronounce *Schizophrenie* as *shitsophrenie* /ʃitsofʀeˈniː/ and not *skitsophrenie*  /skitsofʀeˈniː/. So it's only partially pronounced the way Germans do.

Comment: yes thank you @tchrist . I'd edit my answer but for some reason there's no option to.

Comment: @V0ight There's no option to edit because you posted a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Kit Z. Fox That's a non-sequitur if I ever saw one. I don't see why 'you can't edit' naturally follows from 'it's a comment'.

Comment: @V0ight Comments are only editable for five minutes after you post them. Answers are editable forever. There's no option to edit your 'answer' because it's a comment and not an answer, so it can't be edited.

Comment: @Kit Z. Fox That's a reason I suppose. Not a good reason, but a reason nonetheless. btw, shouldn't this question be closed for lack of research effort? A simple google search shows the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems to be provided in the comments, so I'm summing up the comments just to mark this question answered.

As everyone says in the comment, the reason for the /ts/ sound is the German origin of the word.